# wait for lodash find finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, lodash

I'm using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) in my **NodeJS** app. I want to use `_.find`. 
But I have to wait for `_.find` to finish so I can use the *found* information, or else it will be `undefined` when I want to use it.

```
var items = [
  { id: 001 
    // Super Object
    // +150 properties each
  },
  { id: 002 } // up to 200
];

var foundItem = _.find ( items , { id: 002 });

console.log(foundItem);
// => logs Undefined
```

How can I do it? I need to wait for lodash `_.find` to finish to be able to print the found item.

Comment: Why do you think `_.find` is async ? this code return the object with the id 2

Comment: Because when I print the variable it's undefined, or am I missing something?

Comment: `find` isn't async, your example is working on a fiddle. Are you loading lodash correctly?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm using it well in my node app. But when I use find I have a problem. I don't know if it's a problem, but `items` var is a big array of objects and each object has 150 or more properties.

Comment: Your snippet is the correct usage of lodash anyway (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmer3v0b/3/)), it must be something else then.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/1578/ - example provided by you is working.

Comment: Well, provided jsfiddles works.  
But my `items` variable has +200 objects, and each one has more than 150 properties. Is `find` ok with that? I thought it was a little big for lodash find so it was going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing that you've written your ids as `001` I'm going to guess that they are strings and not numbers, so perhaps quoting your value will do the trick:

```
var foundItem = _.find ( items , { id: '002' });
```

Comment: I'm going to check it. But I think there are numbers in **items** too

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. What a dumb time... Thank you all.